# Constructability of algebraic elements over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, geometric-construction

I'm currently reading upon the classical straightedge and compass constructions and I came across the following theorem:

lf a real number $c$ is constructible, then $c$ is algebraic of degree a power of $2$ over the field $\mathbb{Q}$.

My question is, is the converse to the above theorem true? That is, if $c$ is algebraic of degree a power of $2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, is $c$ constructible?

Comment: You need a tower of quadratic extensions for $c$ to be constructible.

Comment: All you can do with constructions is field operations and square roots.

Comment: Got it, thanks for all the helpful responses!